# Rcpp Create DataFrame with Variable Number of Columns

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am interested in using Rcpp to create a data frame with a variable number of columns. By that, I mean that the number of columns will be known only at runtime. Some of the columns will be standard, but others will be repeated n times where n is the number of features I am considering in a particular run.

I am aware that I can create a data frame as follows:

```
IntegerVector i1(3); i1[0]=4;i1[1]=2134;i1[2]=3453;
IntegerVector i2(3); i2[0]=4123;i2[1]=343;i2[2]=99123;
DataFrame df = DataFrame::create(Named("V1")=i1,Named("V2")=i2);
```

but in this case it is assumed that the number of columns is 2.

To simplify the explanation of what I need, assume that I would like pass a SEXP variable specifying the number of columns to create in the variable part. Something like:

```
RcppExport SEXP myFunc(SEXP n, SEXP <other stuff>)
IntegerVector i1(3); <compute i1>
IntegerVector i2(3); <compute i2>
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){compute vi}
DataFrame df = DataFrame::create(Named("Num")=i1,Named("ID")=i2,...,other columns v1 to vn);
```

where n is passed as an argument. The final data frame in R would look like

```
Num ID V1 ... Vn
  1  2  5     'aasda'
  ...
```

(In reality, the column names will not be of the form "Vx", but they will be known at runtime.) In other words, I cannot use a static list of

```
Named()=...
```

since the number will change.

I have tried skipping the "Named()" part of the constructor and then naming the columns at the end, but the results are junk.

Can this be done?

Comment: Would you be opposed to passing a list of a two-column data frame, and an n-element list? Then you could use `as.data.frame` in R to bind them together in a data frame. The second element of your list (i.e. your n-element list of vectors) can be created as a vector of vectors (i.e. `std::vector<std::vector <double> >`) and use `Rcpp::wrap` to convert it to an R list of vectors.

Comment: Good solution @Bridgeburners. There's no real overhead with the `as.data.frame` conversion (a `data.frame` is a fancy `list` after all) and this should work. @xbot: remember there's a 20-element limit on `Rcpp::List`s and `Rcpp::DataFrame`s

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this exchange. I thought `DataFrame`'s were different than objects of class-'data.frame'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems like it would be easiest to take advantage of the `DataFrame` constructor that takes a `List` as an argument (since the size of a `List` can be specified directly), and set the names of your columns via `.attr("names")` and a `CharacterVector`:

---

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::DataFrame myFunc(int n, Rcpp::List lst, 
                       Rcpp::CharacterVector Names = Rcpp::CharacterVector::create()) {

  Rcpp::List tmp(n + 2);
  tmp[0] = Rcpp::IntegerVector(3);
  tmp[1] = Rcpp::IntegerVector(3);

  Rcpp::CharacterVector lnames = Names.size() < lst.size() ?
    lst.attr("names") : Names;
  Rcpp::CharacterVector names(n + 2);
  names[0] = "Num";
  names[1] = "ID";

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // tmp[i + 2] = do_something(lst[i]);
    tmp[i + 2] = lst[i];
    if (std::string(lnames[i]).compare("") != 0) {
      names[i + 2] = lnames[i];
    } else {
      names[i + 2] = "V" + std::to_string(i);
    }
  }
  Rcpp::DataFrame result(tmp);
  result.attr("names") = names;
  return result;
}
```

---

There's a little extra going on there to allow the `Names` vector to be optional - e.g. if you just use a named list you can omit the third argument.

---

```
lst1 <- list(1L:3L, 1:3 + .25, letters[1:3])
##
> myFunc(length(lst1), lst1, c("V1", "V2", "V3"))
#  Num ID V1   V2 V3
#1   0  0  1 1.25  a
#2   0  0  2 2.25  b
#3   0  0  3 3.25  c

lst2 <- list(
  Column1 = 1L:3L,
  Column2 = 1:3 + .25,
  Column3 = letters[1:3],
  Column4 = LETTERS[1:3])
##
> myFunc(length(lst2), lst2)
#  Num ID Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
#1   0  0       1    1.25       a       A
#2   0  0       2    2.25       b       B
#3   0  0       3    3.25       c       C
```

---

Just be aware of the 20-length limit for [this signature](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/generated/DataFrame_generated.h) of the `DataFrame` constructor, as pointed out by @hrbrmstr.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like what I was after.

Comment: @nrussell do you mean that we cannot use more than 20 columns for dataframe objects in Rcpp?

Comment: @Prometheus You can use more. It's just that there are only 20 functions to make a DataFrame from a List. There's one with 1 column, one with 2 columns and so on. Both C++ and R can use more than 20 columns, it's just the conversion that is limited. Have a look at my answer for a way to have C++ tell R to handle the conversion. That works for any number of columns.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but I think more people are struggling with this, like me. Starting from the other answers here, I arrived at a solution that isn't limited by the 20 column limit of the DataFrame constructor:

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List variableColumnList(int numColumns=30) {
    List retval;
    for (int i=0; i<numColumns; i++) {
        std::ostringstream colName;
        colName << "V" << i+1;
        retval.push_back( IntegerVector::create(100*i, 100*i + 1),colName.str());
    }
    return retval;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame variableColumnListAsDF(int numColumns=30) {
    Function asDF("as.data.frame");

    return asDF(variableColumnList(numColumns));
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame variableColumnListAsTibble(int numColumns=30) {
    Function asTibble("tbl_df");

    return asTibble(variableColumnList(numColumns));
}
```

So build a C++ `List` first by pushing columns onto an empty `List`. (I generate the values and the column names on the fly here.) Then, either return that as an R `list`, or use one of two helper functions to convert them into a `data.frame` or `tbl_df`. One could do the latter from R, but I find this cleaner.